# Can you make "an invisible border"?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to [make a navbar](http://jsbin.com/imuwe4) as an exercise.

I'm using `a:hover` to include a solid border around the button being hovered. However, this makes all the other buttons move by the size of the border.

What is the proper fix to this problem? I know there are others (discussed [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuL2tSlJtSk&feature=player_embedded)), I specifically tried to make the border "be invisible yet take up space even when not hovered". I set `border:transparent` hoping it might do what I want, but it did not show take space at all.

I know I could hand pick the border's color to be equal to the background and make it solid, but this is not what I want. Is there a sane way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

How about `border: 10px solid transparent` ?

Comment: I'll accept this because it seems the cleanest solution, although @derekerdmann's answer is also good and is cross platform (this solution is said not to work in IE 6). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790615/can-you-make-an-invisible-border/5790638#5790638

Answer (score 22):

Your best option would be to add padding or margins to your element that's the same size as the border and make the border have zero width, and then show the border and remove the padding with the `a:hover` selector.

Here's a sample. You can often do this with margins too.

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2em; width: 100px;
    padding: 2px;
    background: #0ff;
}

a:hover {
    padding: 0;
    border :2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello World</a>
```

Comment: How about @Phliplip's suggestion? (comment)

Comment: @Phliplip's solution works too, as long as you don't have to support IE6.  I've been dealing with this long enough that I automatically went to the fully cross-browser solution.  Use whatever makes the most sense for your site and your client's needs.

Answer (score 5):

One reason this isn't working as you'd expect is because you are only applying `display:block` on `:hover`, it needs to be applied to the element without the :hover selector or you will get the "shifting" dimensions. It doesn't matter which display type you use, you just have to make sure they are the same, and by default `<a>` is inline.

Another reason has something to do with your shorthand borders, you need to add a border type for the transparent version like `solid` instead of `none`.

The technique you are using is totally legit, no need for padding hacks or outline (which doesn't add dimension).

http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/kwdDB/

Try this:

```
#wd-navbar li a {
     border: medium solid transparent;
     display: block;
     margin: 1px;
}

#wd-navbar li a:hover {
     background-color: #F5DEB3;
     border: medium solid;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`outline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#dynamic-outlines) CSS property instead of your border, which acts like a border but isn't taken into account in the sizing calculations.

However, this does have some issues, [not being supported by IEs 7 or earlier](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css?uas=IE6-IE7-IE8-FX2-FX3-OP9#support-css2propsbasic-outline).

Answer (score 4):

`border:transparent` means `border: transparent 0 none`

If you don't specify a property when using shorthand syntax then you reset all the properties to their defaults.

You need to give it a border-style and a border-width.

Answer (score 2):

Setting border-color : transparent ;  does the job.

```
a {
  border-color : transparent ;
}

a:hover {
   border-color : black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use pseudo elements `::after` and `::before` to ceate invisible boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that transparent border is just useful when you don't have any box-shadow on the element. Have a look at the image:

[image: transparent border issue when there is shadow]